# ES6 return from internal function

Tags: node.js, promise

I have some code on my back end that I am using to try and verify apple purchase receipts with the library **node-iap**.

I've got all the receipt to verify but I am struggling with something really simple:

Trying to get the code to return out of the **iap.verifyPayment** method to carry on with the code execution in the subscribe method and return a success. It just hangs within handleAppleSub and doesn't return.

```
export const subscribe = (req, res, next) => {
    return User.findOne({
        where: {
            ID: req.params.ID
        }
    })
    .then(
        user =>
            user
                ? req.body.OS == "android"
                    ? handleAndroidSub(user, req.body.receipt)
                    : handleAppleSub(user, req.body.receipt)
                : notFound(res)
    )
    .then(success(res))
    .catch(next);
};

const handleAppleSub = (user, receipt) => {
    var platform = "apple";


    var payment = {
        receipt: receipt.transactionReceipt,
        productId: receipt.productId,
        packageName: "com.app.test",
        secret: appleSecret,
        excludeOldTransactions: true
     };

     return iap.verifyPayment(platform, payment, function(error, response) {

        user.dataValues.SubAppleReceipt = receipt.transactionReceipt;

        return User.update(user.dataValues, {
             where: { ID: user.dataValues.ID }
        }).then(user => {
           return user;
     });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You are returning a Promise from async call. Promisify `iap.verifyPayment`.

Comment: iap.verifyaPayment comes back as an object not a function when attempting to promisfy?

Comment: "iap.verifyaPayment comes back as an object not a function " if this is in case how do you expect your current implementation to even work? You are calling it as if it was a function. `iap.verifyPayment(platform, payment, function(error, response) {`

Comment: I'm following what the documentation is specifying and putting my logic inside the result. Wanting to return out of that function once done.

Comment: A promise returned from a nodeback will not percolate upwards as would a promise returned from a `.then()` callback.
Promise chains are special in this regard. 
The standard way to approach this would be to promisify `iap.verifyPayment`, as say `iap.verifyPaymentAsync`, then call the promisified version and chain `.then(...)`.

Comment: This might be going over my head but how I am to promisfy iap.verifyPayment if its part of the library node-iap?

Comment: See the accepted answer to [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22519785/3478010).